# Generate a Pandas DataFrame from Pre-made Lists? ("5 columns passed, passed data had 500 columns")

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to generate a dataframe like this:

```
# Generate/import the data for each column for student.csv
student_age = random.randint(4, 13, size = (500))
student_sex = random.choice(["Male", "Female"], size = (500))
student_id = list(range(1,501))
student_name_english = pd.read_csv('Database\student_name_local.csv')
student_name_local = pd.read_csv('Database\student_name_english.csv')
# Create an array from the above lists
data = [student_id, student_name_local, student_name_english, student_age, student_sex]
# Create a dataframe from the above array
column_names = ['STUDNET_ID', 'STUDENT_NAME_LOCAL', 'STUDENT_NAME_ENGLISH', 'STUDENT_AGE', 'STUDENT_SEX']
students = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = column_names)
students
```

However, it results in the error below. I know what the error means, but I don't know how to fix it given how I'm attempting to generate rows. I want the list of each of the `student_` variables to be the rows of their respective column name in `column_names`.

Have also tried `data = list(zip(student_id, student_name_local, student_name_english, student_age, student_sex))`, but this only results in a dataframe with a shape of (1, 5).

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    495     try:
--> 496         result = _convert_object_array(
    497             content, columns, dtype=dtype, coerce_float=coerce_float

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _convert_object_array(content, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    579             # caller's responsibility to check for this...
--> 580             raise AssertionError(
    581                 f"{len(columns)} columns passed, passed data had "

AssertionError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 500 columns

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-a2d3f710d196> in <module>
      1 # Create a dataframe from the above array
      2 column_names = ['STUDNET_ID', 'STUDENT_NAME_LOCAL', 'STUDENT_NAME_ENGLISH', 'STUDENT_AGE', 'STUDENT_SEX']
----> 3 students = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = column_names)
      4 students

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    472                     if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
    473                         columns = data[0]._fields
--> 474                     arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
    475                     columns = ensure_index(columns)
    476 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    459         return [], []  # columns if columns is not None else []
    460     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 461         return _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
    462     elif isinstance(data[0], abc.Mapping):
    463         return _list_of_dict_to_arrays(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    498         )
    499     except AssertionError as e:
--> 500         raise ValueError(e) from e
    501     return result
    502 

ValueError: 5 columns passed, passed data had 500 columns
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
column_names = ['STUDNET_ID', 'STUDENT_NAME_LOCAL', 'STUDENT_NAME_ENGLISH', 'STUDENT_AGE', 'STUDENT_SEX']

students = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
students['STUDNET_ID'] = student_id
students['STUDENT_NAME_LOCAL'] = student_name_local
......
```

Comment: That did it! I can't believe I didn't think of that lol. Thank you!! :D

Comment: Oops! I thought I did. Sorry!